# Integral $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\log\big( \mu(\theta)+\sqrt{\mu^2(\theta)-1} \big)\ d\theta, \quad \mu(\theta)=\frac{1+2\cos\theta}{2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hi I am trying to calculate this integral:
$$
I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\log\left( \frac{1+2\cos\theta}{2}+\sqrt{\bigg( \frac{1+2\cos\theta}{2}   \bigg)^2-1}         \right)\ d\theta.
$$
The integral evaluation is related to Mahler measures.  You may also recognize that it is related to the evaluation of log-sine integrals at $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$.
This integral $I$ is somewhat related to
$$
\int_0^1\log\big|2a+2b\cos (2\pi \theta)\big|\ d\theta=\log \big( |a|+\sqrt{a^2-b^2} \big),
$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|a|\geq|b|> 0$. This can be seen in Gradstein and Ryzhik's tables of integrals, but I am not sure how to use that to help me to solve $I$.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help:

$$\int_1^{(1+2\cos \theta)/2} \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} = \left.\log\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)\right|_1^{(1+2\cos \theta)/2}=\log\left(\frac{1+2\cos \theta}{2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+2\cos \theta}{2}\right)^2-1}\right)$$

so your integral is really

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\left(\int_1^{(1+2\cos\theta)/2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)d\theta$$

Comment: thats the same integral we started with after performing the definite integral over u, you will be back with a logarithmic integral in terms of $\theta$

Comment: Ah. I just wanted to throw that out there in case someone does know how to solve it through the double integral.

Comment: @EugeneBulkin Well Thank you! I mean, I am not sure how to work with it because we cannot switch the order of integration

Comment: You can, actually:

$$\int_0^{\pi/3}\int_1^{(1+2\cos\theta)/2} f(u)du d\theta = \int_1^{3/2}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}(u-1/2)}f(u)d\theta du$$

You can check with Mathematica (not sure if Wolfram Alpha will do it) that these are the same. They're approximately 0.789578.

Comment: @EugeneBulkin Okay If you can work it out please share, thanks!

Comment: I accidentally hit enter; I edited the previous comment.

Comment: @EugeneBulkin okay what to do from there, feel free post to this as an answer.  I am looking for a complete solution I am not sure I can follow this/think it will work

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know if there is/how to find a closed form for the integral; it basically turns into:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_1^{3/2}\frac{\cos^{-1}(u-1/2)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} du$$

Comment: @EugeneBulkin Okay yeah that looks very challenging too, Thanks a lot for your help though

Comment: @EugeneBulkin thanks for your help, I also am able to make no progress with this integral....

Comment: I'll try my luck to evaluate this integral Jeff. :D

Comment: Why $f$ instead of $u$ in the title? Because this takes more vertical space?

Comment: @Did Thanks, good point! I fixed it!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral can be expressed in terms of a series of Gauss hypergeometric functions. It is doubtfull that it would be possible to go further on this way.

$I = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\ln\left(\mu(\theta)+\sqrt{\mu^2(\theta)-1}\right)d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\cosh^{-1}(\mu(\theta))$, where $\mu(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}+\cos(\theta)$.

$$\cosh^{-1}(\mu)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(k+1/2)}{2^{k-1/2}(2k+1)k!\sqrt{\pi}}(\mu-1)^{k+1/2}$$
so
$$\mu(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}+\cos(\theta)\to I = \frac{1}{\pi^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(k+1/2)}{2^{k-1/2}(2k+1)k!}(\cos(\theta)-1/2)^{k+1/2}$$

Let $I_k = \int(cos(\theta) - 1/2)^{k+1/2}d\theta$. Then
$$I_k = -\frac{1}{(2k+3)2^k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}(2\cos(\theta)-1)^{k+3/2}F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+\frac{5}{2};\frac{1}{3}(1-2\cos(\theta)),2\cos(\theta)-1\right)+C$$
where $C$ is some constant and $F_1$ is the [Appell hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) of two variables.

$2\cos(0)-1=1$, $2\cos(\pi/3)-1=0$, and $F_1(a;b,b;c;-1/3,1)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}_2F_1(a,b;c-b;-1/3)$, so
$$I_k=\frac{1}{(2k+3)2^k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{\Gamma(k+5/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(k+2)} {}_2F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+2;-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
$$I_k=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}\frac{(2k+1)\Gamma(k+1/2)}{2^{k+2}(k+1)!} {}_2F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+2;-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Finally, from $I = \frac{1}{\pi^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(k+1/2)}{2^{k-1/2}(2k+1)k!}I_k$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/3}\ln\left(\mu(\theta)+\sqrt{\mu^2(\theta)-1}\right)d\theta=\boxed{\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\Gamma(k+1/2))^2}{2^{2k+1}(2k+1)k!(k+1)!} {}_2F_1\left(k+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+2;-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$

Comment: What is this? Why did you not use LaTeX? Your answer seems correct although it's so difficult to me to understand it.

Comment: Did you check this numerically?  I will also wait for other solutions in the meantime.  Thanks

Comment: @ Integrals : Yes, I checked it numerically. The result is approximately 0.251330433713252231 The series is fast convergent. This allows an accurate computation insofar the hypergeometric function can be computed with a sufficient accurency. Of course, my contribution is not a full answer to the question because it is not a closed form such as expected. You are right to wait for a more complete answer.

Comment: @JJacquelin Since this is the only answer posted, and is correct despite not being a closed form.  I still award you +400.  Thanks very much, however I am still looking for a closed form.  But for now, this is great.  Thanks again